# Use JavaScript to update the contents of a script tag dynamically

Tags: javascript

This click event works:

```
document.getElementById('control').addEventListener('click', function(){

   alert('test');

});
```

Why can't I make it the content of a script tag that already exists on the page?

```
var s = document.getElementsByTagName("script")[0];
s.innerHTML = "document.getElementById('control').addEventListener('click', function(){alert('test');});";
```

I've tried enclosing the attempt to do something in an IIFE:

```
s.innerHTML = "(function(){alert('test')}());";
```

so that it will call itself.

Also:

```
s.innerHTML = "var f = function(){alert('f')}; f();"
```

I'm only interested theoretically and in no way am saying this is a good or bad idea, but how could I make it work?

Comment: Program in `file` form differs from program in `execution` form. You are trying to modify the code itself while the code is loaded and is running in the RAM. Instead, you need to add new dynamic functionality or you should fetch new code from some location.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Script tags are evaluated once and code is not replaced if you change their contents (they work differently than other types of tags in this regard).  If you want to add new code to the page, you can simply add new script tags to the page that contains the new code.  If you want to redefine existing publicly accessible functions, you can simply redefine them with new code.

So, if you want to replace a previous definition of `function f()`, you can simply assign new code to that symbol:

```
f = function() {alert("new f");}
```

You can insert new scripts from a remote source at any time with a code snippet like this:

```
var s = document.createElement("script");
s.type = "text/javascript";
s.src = url;
document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(s);
```

---

It is also possible to use `eval()` to pass text to the javascript engine that you want it to parse and then run, but there are rarely any good reasons to do it this way as there are generally better ways to solve a problem like this.

Comment: You can also add script as the *text* attribute of a newly created script element.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what jfriend00 said. If you want to dynamically execute scripts. Use should probably use JavaScript's [eval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval) function.

**Note: But use it carefully!!!**

Comment: thank you. that does work. why does `eval` trigger execution? jfriend says that the scripts are only evaluated once. `eval` seems not to adhere to that rule. What's up with that?

Comment: @thomas - `eval()` allows you to pass text to the javsacript engine and ask it to parse it and run it - this has nothing to do with previous script tags.  There are rarely good reasons to use it because if you know what code you're going to run, you can just put that code in your page in the first place or load it remotely as I've shown in my answer.

Comment: `eval` is a special function in almost every language to evaluate a script manually. It's nowhere related to `<script>`

Comment: Not sure what's your question then!

Answer (score 0):

you can't do this with an existing script tag, you have to create a new script tag and push your script before adding it to the DOM:

```
var sc =document.createElement("script");
sc.type="text/javascript";
var scriptText=document.createTextNode("document.getElementById('control').addEventListener('click', function(){"+
        "alert('test');" +
    "});");
sc.appendChild(scriptText);
document.querySelector("head").appendChild(sc);
```

and it will do what you want.

The important point here, once the first script in a script tag is executed, you no longer can inject any script in it, actually you can, but it won't work.

Comment: Setting the innerHTML of a script element should not cause the script to execute (it throws an error in some browser). Better (i.e. it will work) to assign it to the *text* property.